# how to install juju on Maas environment?

Tags: 14.04, juju, maas, openstack, wordpress

I would like to know where I have to install Juju with Maas to deploy Wordpress first ? and Openstack later ?

Is it in my maas server ? or
Is it in one of my node ?

Answer (score 0):

You can start simple, install juju in the same server where you have MaaS.

What you want now is to get the latest juju from the ppa:

`apt-get install python-software-properties`

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juju/stable`

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install juju-core`

Now the juju configuration:

`juju generate-config`

Follow the documentation about the configuration [here](https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/config-maas)